# Geometry Nodes - Delete mesh line verts based on the offset

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm learning geometry nodes by creating a node for chairs. I want to make a backrest with rungs and I want to delete the rung if it would get higher than the actual backrest.

So for now I created a node that based on the height of the backrest increase or decrease the count for the mesh line used for the rungs (I'm using vector as an input as I would need it for other parts of the chair as well). However, this takes a constant 0.0,0.0,0.3 offset and will not work with different values.
[image: backrest with 0.3 offset]

And I'm currently trying to figure out how the rungs can be added depending on both offset and height of the backrest while not being higher or lower.

I was trying to multiply the count value so the actual value would be lower or higher depending on the offset but I feel there isa simpler way

[image: backrest with different offset]

Thank you for every advice!

Comment: i think you would attract more (lazy) people (like me) to help you if you provide a blend file. Imagine people want help from you. Would you help those people who prepared everything to make it easy for you to help or would you prefer helping those people where you first have to do a lot yourself before you can help them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want features like this:

[image]
[image]

At the `Resample curve` node, select the *Count* or *Length* you need:

[image]

Comment: thank you! I was playing with delete geometry but I will definitely try this one too!